# javascript onscroll fade same class but with different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I am really new at JavaScript and I want to learn something new.

There is something wrong with my code : Why my `div` fades at the same time.

I just want to ask how to fade different `div`s with same `class` name.can someone help me and explain that to me.

Thanks in advance.

## Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($( "div.fade" ).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() <= 100){
       $('.fade').addClass( "fade-in");
  }
  else {
       $('.fade').removeClass("fade-in");
  }
});
```

here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wekdohb3/2/)

Comment: so you want to be able to choose which div to unfade/fade??

Comment: yes, i want my div work separately is it possible with same class name ?

Comment: requirement is not really clear.. elaborate more please

Comment: its look like this: when the first div is > 100 then the second div wont fade  but when the second div > 100 the second div will fading in and the first one is fading out

Comment: do you mean whichever div with class fade passes the >100 condition should be faded in and remaining divs should not fade in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onscroll = function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() ;

    $("div.fade").each(function(){
         if(($(this).offset().top - scrollTop) <= 100){
            $(this).toggleClass("fade-in");
         }
    })
}
```

Comment: Provided you mean whichever div with class fade passes the >100 condition should be faded in and remaining divs should not fade in

Comment: yah thank you dude,its look like i should use toggleClass instead of addClass and removeClass

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose *which* div with the class `fade` you want to fade in/out.

You can use the [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($("div.fade").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() <= 100) {
        $('.fade:eq(0)').addClass("fade-in"); //eq(0) chooses the FIRST div with this class on the page
    } else {
        $('.fade').removeClass("fade-in");
    };
});
```

So this code would only fade-in the first div with `fade` class.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wekdohb3/3/)